# Tensorflow 2; How to create custom layer/gradient with a predifined sparse weight architecture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sparse-matrix, backpropagation

My goal is to create a custom layer in Tensorflow 2 with a predefined, fixed, and sparse weight structure. For memory reasons, we need to keep the weight matrix in the form of a trainable SparseTensor.

Our solution thus far is to represent the weights/values of the SparseTensor as a standard trainable object in a custom layer ("self.w"), and to deal with the sparse matrix operations and back-propagation using a custom layer ("matmul_dense_sparse").

My question is, how do I back-propagate over the sparse network architecture with a custom gradient?

Here is a toy example (TF 2.1.0; executing eagerly):

```
import numpy as np
tf.__version__
# 2.1.0


@tf.custom_gradient
def matmul_dense_sparse(dense, sparse_mat):
    sparse_mat = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_mat)
    sparse_indices = sparse_mat.indices
    ta  = tf.transpose(dense)
    b   = sparse_mat
    tb  = tf.sparse.transpose(b)
    res = tf.transpose(tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(tb, ta))

    def grad_fn(grad_res):
        print(grad_res)
        tgrad              = tf.transpose(grad_res)
        grad_dense         = tf.transpose(tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(b, tgrad))
        dense_edge_starts  = tf.gather(dense, sparse_indices[:, 0], axis=1)
        grad_res_edge_ends = tf.gather(grad_res, sparse_indices[:, 1], axis=1)
        grad_values        = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(dense_edge_starts, grad_res_edge_ends), axis=0)
        return grad_dense, grad_values

    return res, grad_fn


# custom layer with sparse weight architecture
class SparseLinear(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, indices, units=32):
        super(SparseLinear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        self.indices = indices

    def build(self, input_shape):

        # self.w corresponds to the trainable "values" in the sparse tensor
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(self.indices.shape[0],),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 trainable=True)
        self.sparse_mat = tf.sparse.reorder(tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=self.indices, values=self.w, dense_shape=[input_shape[-1], self.units]))

    def call(self, x):
        return matmul_dense_sparse(x, self.sparse_mat)


# non-zero weights in SparseTensor
sp_idxs  = np.array([[0, 2],[1, 2], [8, 1], [9, 3], [10, 5]])

train_x = np.random.rand(20, 100)
train_y = np.random.rand(20, 1)

# build keras model
n_features = train_x.shape[1]
inputs     = tf.keras.Input(shape=(n_features,), name='snp_input')
layers     = SparseLinear(indices=sp_idxs, units=32)(inputs)
layers     = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='linear')(layers)
layers     = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(layers)
model      = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layers, name='model')

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y)
weights = model.get_weights()
```

And corresponding error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-34c364b12112> in <module>()
     51 n_features = train_x.shape[1]
     52 inputs     = tf.keras.Input(shape=(n_features,), name='snp_input')
---> 53 layers     = Linear(indices=sp_idxs, units=32)(inputs)
     54 layers     = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='linear')(layers)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    771                     not base_layer_utils.is_in_eager_or_tf_function()):
    772                   with auto_control_deps.AutomaticControlDependencies() as acd:
--> 773                     outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    774                     # Wrap Tensors in `outputs` in `tf.identity` to avoid
    775                     # circular dependencies.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    238         else:
    239           raise

TypeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-11-34c364b12112>:37 call  *
        return matmul_dense_sparse(x, self.sparse_mat)
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/custom_gradient.py:256 __call__
        return self._d(self._f, a, k)
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/custom_gradient.py:212 decorated
        return _graph_mode_decorator(wrapped, args, kwargs)
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/custom_gradient.py:307 _graph_mode_decorator
        args = [ops.convert_to_tensor(x) for x in args]
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/custom_gradient.py:307 <listcomp>
        args = [ops.convert_to_tensor(x) for x in args]
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1314 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py:317 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py:258 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py:296 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /home/kma52/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py:547 make_tensor_proto
        "supported type." % (type(values), values))

    TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
    [[ 0  2]
     [ 1  2]
     [ 8  1]
     [ 9  3]
     [10  5]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([ 0.03837506 -0.07365214 -0.02256368 -0.05631712  0.05937713], shape=(5,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([100  32], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

This code is attempting to implement insights from these prior threads: [post #1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6998), [post #2](https://gist.github.com/laci37/b7bcb88a08ed09e298b6bf34393ad80b), [post #3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32215)

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution that seems to be working well:

```
class SparseLinear(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, indices, units=32):
        super(SparseLinear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        self.indices = indices

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.n_feat = input_shape[-1]
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(len(self.indices),),
                                 initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),
                                 trainable=True)

    def call(self, x):
        kernel = tf.SparseTensor(self.indices, self.w, [self.n_feat, self.units])
        return tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(x, kernel)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow batched multiplication a la `tensordot` and will break on non-2D inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented such a layer in tensorflow 1.13.1 see:

https://github.com/ArnovanHilten/GenNet/blob/master/utils/LocallyDirectedConnected.py

For tensorflow 2:

https://github.com/ArnovanHilten/GenNet/blob/master/utils/LocallyDirectedConnected_tf2.py