# tensorflow sparse dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, layer

I want to create a custom dense layer in tf.keras, which works with sparse weight matrices. My weight matrices are zero almost everywhere, and I know the sparsity pattern. It would be a huge cost saving. How would I incorporate sparse matrices into a custom Dense layer? Could someone point me to a reference? I could not find this functionality in tf. Edit: the layer should be trainable.

Comment: Is this for inference only, or you want a trainable sparse layer?

Comment: I want it to be trainable. Sorry, I should have been more clear. Edited my question now.

Comment: Check- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153815/tensorflow-2-how-to-create-custom-layer-gradient-with-a-predifined-sparse-weigh